# boost_python hello example not working

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I am trying to get the hello world example for boost python working. I am using `OSX`, `boost 1.55` and `python 2.7`

Here is my `hello.cpp`

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

and I have compiled it with the following two lines:

```
g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -I/usr/local/include/ -c hello.cpp
g++ -shared -Wl, -o hello.so hello.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lpython2.7 -lboost_python
```

When I try to import it into python by doing import `hello.so` I get the following error:

`ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (inithello)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the name in the `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` must match the name of the library so I changed the linking step to

```
g++ -shared -Wl, -o hello_ext.so hello.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lpython2.7 -lboost_python
```